# AJAX call passing always true for checkbox data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax call is always passing true for isHalfDay checkbox, every other value that is being passed is correct apart from this one. What might be the reason?

```
UpdateDays: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#numberOfDays").data("url"),
        data: {
            startDate: $("input[name=StartDate]").val(),
            endDate: $("input[name=EndDate]").val(),
            employeeId: $("#holiday-editor").data("employee"),
            isHalfDay: $("input[name=HalfDay]").val()
        },
        method: "POST"
    }).success(function (response) {
        $("#numberOfDays").html(response);
        $("#Days").val(response);
    });
```

Comment: please show the relevant html also

Comment: Because there are 2 inputs generated by `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` both with `name="HalfDay"`, one with `value="true"` and one with `value="false"`.

Comment: use `isHalfDay: $("#HalfDay").is(":checked");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the checkbox *always* has a value. If you want to know if it's checked or not use `prop('checked')`, like this:

```
isHalfDay: $("input[name=HalfDay]").prop('checked')
```

Also note that there is no `success()` method on the promise returned from the `$.ajax` call - I think you mean `done()` instead.